# How can I get a UK tourist visa after two rejections from Canada?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

My Canada tourist visa got rejected twice. I am 25yrs old, single, and I applied to visit my sister in Canada but was rejected due to

- travel history
- Financial situation (I showed funds of inr 7lacs)
- Ties to return home country

I want to apply for a tourist visa for the UK. I was in the UK in 2011 for two weeks on a family visit visa. Will the visa rejection by Canada will affect my UK visa?

Comment: This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e discusses the typical refusal for a U.K. visit visa

Comment: In 2011 you were probably a minor and thus qualified for a visa based not on your own merits. As an adult you essentially have to qualify on your own and it doesn’t look like you have a strong profile. Very likely you suffer another rejection.

Comment: Related: [How to create a travel history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65508/3221)

Answer (score 4):

Two rejections from Canada will certainly count against you if you apply to the UK. How much of an issue this will be will depend on the strength of your application overall. Your previous history will help.

You have listed reasons why your Canadian visa application failed. Your UK application is likely to fail for the same reasons, so the question is, what have you done to address them, and will it satisfy the UK authorities?

We have no way to answer that.

You might consider consulting a UK lawyer with immigration experience to help you complete your application. This will improve your chances but won't come cheap.

Comment: It's probably not worth paying an immigration lawyer if you're just going on holiday: go somewhere that's easier to get a visa for, instead. The extra travel history will probably be helpful when applying for a UK visa later on.