# Is it possible to get a US visa if I have no travel history?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian and I received an invitation from my uncle to visit him. I am applying for a US visitor visa. I have been rejected 3 times when I was single. Now I am married with a child, but have never travelled outside of my country before. What are my chances of getting the visa?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: The "rejected 3 times" part is **much** more significant than the "no travel history".

Comment: Thank you for your response, presently, I have a new passport which has my husband's surname. Can the number of times I applied show up on my new passports?

Answer (score 25):

> Is it possible to get a US visa if I have no travel history?

**Yes**. My first travel experience was as a visitor to the USA from Ghana which has a pretty similar profile to Nigeria in many respects including immigration statistics to western countries.

That said, your chances of getting a USA visa as your first travel experience **after three successive rejections** are very very very slim. On average, Nigerians have a [44.95% adjusted refusal rate](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY17.pdf) when they apply for USA visitor visas, which is already on the high side. Without knowing (nor needing) any more information about you except what you provided here, I would say your probability of refusal is much higher than the average, maybe two times worse.

My advice to you is to [build a travel history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65508/how-to-create-a-travel-history/65516#65516) in a systematic manner then after a few years you can apply for a USA visa.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The invitation sent to me is scheduled for 9th of January 2019 and am scared of my chances of getting the visa because I don't know how to build traveling history within the short time

Comment: @2rayo: Well, that's not going to work anyway. A sudden, large increase in the number of trips you take, without a good explanation why, could be considered a red flag more than anything else. A pattern of annual 1-2 week vacations is much more logical.

Answer (score 5):

According to what I've seen by many friends and family members applying U.S. visa, the most important thing they check is ... **ties to your country or country of residence compared to reasons to stay in the U.S.**

*Having a stable job in a big company for several years* is a big plus to get USA visa. Travel history also have a positive factor, especially traveling to developed countries. Family ties are important too but other than your spouse and your kids, I think other family does not weigh in much for your visa application.

Comment: What is the motivation for you to return to Nigeria and have you provided this information in your visa application? Also having a home/house that you own, the job, the wife, the children are all factors. From a South African.

Comment: Yes, am now married and have a 1year old child also working in a reputable organization and I also have a small business I do after working hours

Comment: @2rayo Your wife and child are going with you?

Comment: I'm the wife, my husband and baby are not going, the invitation is for me alone

Comment: Family staying behind can be interpreted in two ways: as a reason for OP to go back to her country, or as immigration threat, because if OP will stay as immigrant (illegal, seeking asylum etc), she'll try to bring child to join her. I don't know any way to guess what immigration officer will think about that.