# New Zealand visitor visa refusal: what can I do?

Tags: visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, new-zealand

I had applied for General Visitor Visa to New Zealand online but my application was rejected on these grounds

> As you have limited previous international travel records and there is insufficient evidence on file to demonstrate your detailed intended travel arrangements in New Zealand, we are unable to satisfactorily establish your genuine intent.
>
> While you have provided evidence of funds we are not satisfied the documents you have provided adequately demonstrate financial commitments to your resident country and home country.
>
> While you have provided some evidence of employment, we still have concerns over your overall personal circumstances. We have tried to contact you on 23 November 2018 and 27 November 2018 to gather more information however we could not get in touch with you. Therefore we are unable to be satisfied that you have demonstrated strong commitments to your resident country and home country at this stage.

Now here's my situation: I am 30, a citizen of Pakistan but resident of UAE since birth. My father, after his retirement, purchased an apartment in his name in the UAE. He gave me and my brother special power of attorney so we could be relieved of hefty rents. Never in his entire career did he make any assets/business back in Pakistan, due to personal commitments towards his brothers and sisters there after my grandparents passed away.

I felt I should do something for him in turn; therefore, I took a personal loan and helped him buy a home on his name in our home country. When the time came to sponsor my wife and child in the UAE, I had to get a housing proof letter from the  Ministry of Justice, since apartment is under my father's ownership. Yes, my parents, brother and my family live happily together there now. My brother pays all the bills and I pay for the groceries/insurance for my family.

The reason I don't have a travel history is because I had to settle the loan. Staying back, I have 60 days of accumulated annual leave which could be forfeited if not used.

The reason I did not make any detailed travel arrangements is because I was unsure of my visa outcome and wanted to avoid losing money.

I don't have remittances or tax returns to home country since I'm earning in the UAE and all my family members reside with me. I don't have anything in my name in my home country.

What makes me stay in the UAE is my family (housewife, 3 year old child and a full time job).

I was never called or emailed by New Zealand Immigration.

Will any consulate understand if I share my personal circumstances as I've mentioned here? How do I show strong personal or financial commitments to convince any consulate?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Comment: Getting a visitor visa to any Western country as a Pakistani is nearly impossible without an extensive travel history. Travel to nearby countries with less restrictive visa policies and try New Zealand after a few years. I suggest Sri Lanka, Thailand and Malaysia.

Answer (score 6):

The consular questions are legitimate and you have too many excuses/explanations. Consular officers do not like complicated situations, especially for ordinary tourist/visitor visas.

To their credit they tried contacting you for clarification. A USA consular for example would just deny you straight away. Address their concerns by fixing your life situation.

The convoluted story about buying your father a house etc. If you own a house it should be in your name. If you have funds it should be in your name.

You should show your ties to UAE through clear and convincing evidence of property, family, funds, decent job, etc. You should also [build a travel history](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65508/how-to-create-a-travel-history/65516#65516). Without doing some or preferably all of the above, you are not going to New Zealand anytime soon.

Comment: That's a decent answer but I'm concerned about the first paragraph. What's your source for the claim that consular officers don't like complicated situations?

Comment: @greatone My source is commonsense and personal history and the fact that every immigration expert/attorney  recommends keeping answers to consular officers short and crisp.

Comment: There is a difference between an actually complicated situation and making things unnecessarily complicated. A complicated situation should not be a problem in seeking a visitor visa as long as everything makes sense and the traveler is judged to be credible in his intentions.

Comment: @MT I don’t know how to teach that except say answer questions directly without unnecessary detail. You may need a communication class if I am still not clear.

Comment: @honorary world citizen I did not explain my complicated situation in the personal circumstances section of application like i have done here. I had only submitted proof of accomodation, funds, salary and service letter and details of my family residence showing me as their residence visa sponsor. By fixing my life situation you mean leaving own property and going on rent just to address the concerns of consulates (financial commitments)?

Comment: @MT My philosophy with respect to consular officers has always been _give them what they want to hear/see_. What you explained about your life is perfectly reasonable to me, but to them since they are just looking for any opportunity to deny you, they will use any unusual circumstance to deny you. Also remember Pakistanis traditionally have difficulty obtaining visas to western countries so you have to make sure you stand out in a positive way.